# Issue with Main Page Navigation not Updating after pointing site to directory

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I’ve built a site for a client using a one-page WordPress theme: motorarzt.com

The main navigation on the home page uses Anchors to scroll to the different pages.

I put WordPress in a directory /ma/ and then updated the index.php file and the htacess file as normal. On the main home page the URLS are working fine - and also working fine on the sidebar.

The problem is when I go to a single page with this theme, the main navigation URLs are still showing the directory. Here’s an example: motorarzt.com/services/

The links should be http://motorarzt.com/#services NOT http://motorarzt.com/ma#services

Really hoping someone here can help me out...wondering if this is an issue with how the theme is developed and how i may tweak/fix it.

The theme developer provided me this code to add to the "extra javascript" area in the theme option panel - but it DID NOT work. Then he said he's no longer supporting it.

```
jQuery (document).ready(function($){
$ ("#menu a").each(function(){
var old_a = $(this).attr("href");
var new_a = old_a.replace("ma", "")
$(this).attr("href", new_a)
})
```

thanks! 
Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Try putting semicolons on the last three lines:

```
var new_a = old_a.replace("ma", "");
$(this).attr("href", new_a);
});
```

Also, if you're using a recent version of jQuery, replace attr() with prop().

Oh and if you have caching enabled you should flush all of them.  I use Drupal not Wordpress but I'm guessing it's there too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion above and still no change. 

Any other ideas? I've been troubleshooting this all day :(

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The issue was in the header.php code - the theme developer didn't code the php main navigation code correctly. It's been fixed now.